# Recreate POST request with WebKitFormBoundary using Python's requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape some data from a website using a POST request with the Python `requests` library. Unfortunately I am unable to post a link to the page as you must be signed in to the website to site to use it.

The request I am trying to replicate has the file extension .ehtml and this is part of the Request payload I am looking to recreate:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session_id"

W0pNKn8AAQEAACD-XkYAAAAJ
------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p_session_id"

W0pMOH8AAQEAABZSUVkAAAAD
------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attach_key"


------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="chosen"

0
------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="debug"


------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="language"

en
------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="game_system_id"

NULL
------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="collection_detail_id"

NULL
------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="competition_id"

NULL
```

Using some help from some of the questions on stackoverflow, I have managed to recreate it this far:

```
--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session_id"


--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p_session_id"


--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attach_key"


--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="chosen"

0
--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="debug"


--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="language"

en
--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="game_system_id"

NULL
--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="collection_detail_id"

NULL
--30b11983bde849109a3dc93e139e16d4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="competition_id"

NULL
```

That was done using this code:

```
Q = {
     "session_id" : (None,""),
     "p_session_id" : (None,""),
     "attach_key" : (None,""),
     "chosen" : (None,"0"),
     "debug" : (None,""),
     "language" : (None,"en"),
     "game_system_id" : (None,"NULL"),
     "collection_detail_id" : (None,"NULL"),
     "competition_id" : (None,"NULL")
     }


with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(login_URL2,data=payload)
    #print(p.text)

    #d = s.post(req_url,files=Q)
    d2 = Request("POST",req_url,files=Q)    


d3 = d2.prepare()
print(d3.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

I believe the last thing I am missing is the WebKitFormBoundary part, I am unable to find anywhere how to insert that part. This is my first time scraping using an .ehtml file, so if I have missed anything else obvious, all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact name of the boundary does not matter as long as it is declared in the header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
```

With this header the boundaries would be

```
--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
```

There server will take a look at the `Content-Type` header and figure out the body parts.

Comment: I have tried both of the below headers, but WebKitFormBoundary does not appear in the body:`header = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--WebKitFormBoundary9rntuVzldIBHkILv'}` and `header1 = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=--WebKitFormBoundary9rntuVzldIBHkILv'}`

Comment: But if I'm trying to recreate a request which uses the WebKitFormBoundary, and the request I create instead uses a random string (as in your example) instead, will that not cause a problem?

Comment: @OD1995 have you tried including the same "random" string in request body?

Answer (score 9):

```py
import requests
import random,string
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

fields = {
    'file': ('test.png', your_data, "image/png"),
    'file_id': "0"
}
boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary' \
           + ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 16))
m = MultipartEncoder(fields=fields, boundary=boundary)

headers = {
    "Host": "xxxx",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": m.content_type
}

req = requests.post('https://xxxx/api/upload', headers=headers, data=m)
print(req.text)
```

In this way can we make boundary format like `------WebKitFormBoundary8rntuVzldIBHkILv`.

Answer (score 2):

When you're sending an ajax request via jQuery and you want to send FormData you don't need to use JSON.stringify on this FormData. Also when you're sending file the content type must be multipart/form-data including boundry - something like this multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0BPm0koKA

```
So to send FormData including some file via jQuery ajax you need to:

Set data to the FormData without any modifications.
Set processData to false (Lets you prevent jQuery from automatically transforming the data into a query string).
Set the contentType to false (This is needed because otherwise jQuery will set it incorrectly).
Your request should look like this:

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', dogName);
// ... 
formData.append('file', document.getElementById("dogImg").files[0]);


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/foodoo/index.php?method=insertNewDog",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(errResponse) {
        console.log(errResponse);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

------WebKitFormBoundary89uZMBZwSHfYjySK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="account_number"

blah
------WebKitFormBoundary89uZMBZwSHfYjySK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date_of_birth"

blah
------WebKitFormBoundary89uZMBZwSHfYjySK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"

blah
------WebKitFormBoundary89uZMBZwSHfYjySK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"

blah
------WebKitFormBoundary89uZMBZwSHfYjySK--

I've basically turned those webkitform boundaries into JSON like below:

import requests

data = {
"account_number": blah,
"date_of_birth": "blah",
"first_name": "blah",
"last_name": "blah"
}

headers = {
"authorization": "Bearer blah"
}

req = requests.post('https://rest.blah/v1/blah/sign-in', headers=headers, data=data)
print(req.content)

RESPONSE:

b'{"code":200,"data":{"user_id":"15442","building_id":"11","apartment_id":"4192"}}

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Content-Type header manually means it's missing the boundary parameter. Remove that header and allow fetch to generate the full content type. It will look something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyrV7KO0BoCBuDbTL
```

Fetch knows which content type header to create based on the FormData object passed in as the request body content.